# variable in string sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm working on parsing XML data with the T-SQL nodes function. Here's a sample of the code I'm working on.

```
SELECT
a.b.value('Table1[1]/CURRENCY_FLAG[1]','varchar(10)') AS Currency
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('DataSet/diffgr_diffgram/EA_RESULTS') a(b)

UNION ALL 

SELECT
a.b.value('Table1[2]/CURRENCY_FLAG[1]','varchar(10)') AS Currency
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('DataSet/diffgr_diffgram/EA_RESULTS') a(b)
```

As you can see the only difference between the two sections is Table1[x]. 
Is there any way to increment this number?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include `Table1` to the nodes clause there is no need to increment it and no need to use `union all`.

Try this.

```
SELECT a.b.value('CURRENCY_FLAG[1]','varchar(10)') AS Currency
FROM @XMLdata.nodes('DataSet/diffgr_diffgram/EA_RESULTS/Table1') a(b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I've bee wrecking my head all day. So simple, I feel so silly now. Thanks again!